# How to change options of <select> with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html-select

Suppose a list of options is available, how do you update the `<select>` with new `<option>`s?

Answer (score 701, accepted):

You can remove the existing options by using the [`empty`](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/empty) method, and then add your new options:

```
var option = $('<option></option>').attr("value", "option value").text("Text");
$("#selectId").empty().append(option);
```

If you have your new options in an object you can:

```
var newOptions = {"Option 1": "value1",
  "Option 2": "value2",
  "Option 3": "value3"
};

var $el = $("#selectId");
$el.empty(); // remove old options
$.each(newOptions, function(key,value) {
  $el.append($("<option></option>")
     .attr("value", value).text(key));
});
```

**Edit:** For removing the all the options but the first, you can use the [`:gt`](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/gt) selector, to get all the `option` elements with index greater than zero and [`remove`](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/remove) them:

```
$('#selectId option:gt(0)').remove(); // remove all options, but not the first
```

Comment: How to remain the first option when empty()?

Comment: If using [bootstrap-select](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) then add the following to refresh the select picker after replacing the options: `$('#selectId').selectpicker('refresh');  $('#selectId').selectpicker('render');`. Otherwise the new options will not be visible in your select list.

Comment: How can I check one of this options?

Comment: I personally find this syntax a bit cleaner for creating jQuery node `$el.append($('<option/>', { value: value, text: key }));`

Comment: Thanks guys. if you have to set selected value when we are editing the page for the default selected value we can use something like this in the loop for specific iteration we can add selected $el.append($('<option/>', { value: value, selected: 'selected', text: key }));

Comment: This works fine. If your shown text is swapped with values, just interchange key and value.

Answer (score 85):

I threw CMS's excellent answer into a quick jQuery extension:

```js
(function($, window) {
  $.fn.replaceOptions = function(options) {
    var self, $option;

    this.empty();
    self = this;

    $.each(options, function(index, option) {
      $option = $("<option></option>")
        .attr("value", option.value)
        .text(option.text);
      self.append($option);
    });
  };
})(jQuery, window);
```

It expects an array of objects which contain "text" and "value" keys. So usage is as follows:

```js
var options = [
  {text: "one", value: 1},
  {text: "two", value: 2}
];

$("#foo").replaceOptions(options);
```

Answer (score 20):

```
$('#comboBx').append($("<option></option>").attr("value",key).text(value));
```

where comboBx is your combo box id.

or you can append options as string to the already existing innerHTML and then assign to the select innerHTML.

***Edit***

If you need to keep the first option and remove all other then you can use

```
var firstOption = $("#cmb1 option:first-child");
$("#cmb1").empty().append(firstOption);
```

Comment: Do you want to clear the old ones o just add new options to the existing options?

Answer (score 6):

For some odd reason this part

```js
$el.empty(); // remove old options
```

from CMS solution didn't work for me, so instead of that I've simply used this

```js
el.html(' ');
```

And it's works. So my working code now looks like that:

```js
var newOptions = {
    "Option 1":"option-1",
    "Option 2":"option-2"
};

var $el = $('.selectClass');
$el.html(' ');
$.each(newOptions, function(key, value) {
    $el.append($("<option></option>")
    .attr("value", value).text(key));
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Removing and adding DOM element is slower than modification of existing one.

If your option sets have same length, you may do something like this:

```
$('#my-select option')
.each(function(index) {
    $(this).text('someNewText').val('someNewValue');
});
```

In case your new option set has different length, you may delete/add empty options you really need, using some technique described above.

Answer (score 3):

Does this help?

```
$("#SelectName option[value='theValueOfOption']")[0].selected = true;
```

Comment: This question is about dynamically adding <option> to a <select>, not selecting a specific option.

Comment: Answer may not be relevant to the question, but I found my way here as I was looking for this answer, so it helped.

Answer (score 2):

if we update `<select>` constantly and we need to save previous value :

```
var newOptions = {
    'Option 1':'value-1',
    'Option 2':'value-2'
};

var $el = $('#select');
var prevValue = $el.val();
$el.empty();
$.each(newOptions, function(key, value) {
   $el.append($('<option></option>').attr('value', value).text(key));
   if (value === prevValue){
       $el.val(value);
   }
});
$el.trigger('change');
```

Answer (score 2):

Old school of doing things by hand has always been good for me.

1. Clean the select and leave the first option:

   ```
       $('#your_select_id').find('option').remove()
       .end().append('<option value="0">Selec...</option>')
       .val('whatever');
   ```
2. If your data comes from a Json or whatever (just Concat the data):

   ```
       var JSONObject = JSON.parse(data);
       newOptionsSelect = '';
       for (var key in JSONObject) {
           if (JSONObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
               var newOptionsSelect = newOptionsSelect + '<option value="'+JSONObject[key]["value"]+'">'+JSONObject[key]["text"]+'</option>';
           }
       }

       $('#your_select_id').append( newOptionsSelect );
   ```
3. My Json Objetc:

   ```
       [{"value":1,"text":"Text 1"},{"value":2,"text":"Text 2"},{"value":3,"text":"Text 3"}]
   ```

This solution is ideal for working with Ajax, and answers in Json from a database.

Answer (score 1):

If for example your html code contain this code:

```
<select id="selectId"><option>Test1</option><option>Test2</option></select>
```

In order to change the list of option inside your select, you can use this code bellow. when your name select named **selectId**.

```
var option = $('<option></option>').attr("value", "option value").text("Text");
$("#selectId").html(option);
```

in this example above i change the old list of **option** by only one new option.

Comment: Why should the OP try this? Please add an explanation of what you did and why you did it that way not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 0):

Most approaches start by deleting all the existing options and re-populating the dropdown. However, I prefer to add and remove individual options to avoid altering the current selection, if any.

```
<option></option>
<option value="12151d81-fe94-4007-8f1f-907aa8129d0a" data-text="Scrambled Eggs">Scrambled Eggs</option>
```

This example assumes that the options HTML is structured like the above. `options` is JSON data like the following:

```
{
    "guid": "bf42ba25-02b3-4d49-b4cf-02467c4fc44d",
    "value": "Granola"
},
{
    "guid": "89004730-bb92-4cd6-986a-28e228a94d54",
    "value": "Yogurt"
}
```

`field` is the input object.

```
function update_options(field, options) {
                // If item doesn't exist in dropdown, add it.
                $.each(options, function (index, item) {
                    if (field.find(`option[value="${item.guid}"]`).length == 0) {
                        $(`<option value="${item.guid}" data-text="${item.value}">${item.value}<\/option>`).appendTo(field);
                    }
                });
                // If item in dropdown doesn't exist in data, remove it.
                $.each(field.find('option'), function (index, item) {
                    if (options.find(x => x.guid == item.value) == undefined) {
                        field.find(`option[value="${item.value}"]`).remove();
                    }
                });
            }
```