# Changing <select> Options with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I've read the following post:

[How to change options of <select> with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801499/how-to-change-options-of-select-with-jquery)

However, my document has multiple `<select>`s. How can I choose to change only one of them?

Comment: Well, an id attribute is supposed to be unique, and `document.getElementById('unique')` or jQuery's `$('#id')` selector should work... so does google, btw :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you can assign an id to the select tags i.e

```
<select id="sel1">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>

<select id="another-select">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Then you change the particular SELECT tag that you need:

```
$('#sel1').html('<option value="1">New Option 1</option><option value="2">New Option 2</option><option value="3">New Option 3</option>');
```

Answer (score 3):

Set an ID on it.

```
<select id="changeme">...</select>
....
$("#changeme")....
```

Comment: I was expecting a `document.getElementById('..')` :P