# How can I use jQuery to replace the contents of a select element when the arrow is clicked?

Tags: jquery

I have a select looking like this:

```
    <select name="rowKey_1" id="rowTopic_1">
        <option value="00">Topic 1</option>
    </select>
```

I have many of these in a grid on a table.

What I would like is for when the user clicks on the select arrow I would like jQuery to trigger and then have code that calls a URL and retieves new options. Then I would like to have the one option replaced with my new long option list.

I can code the ajax request but how can I code the jQuery that senses the trigger clicked and then how can I code the jQuery that replaces the options with new options?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801499/how-to-change-options-of-select-with-jquery

Comment: Spend some time to read through the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/), it's worth it, you will learn a lot.

Comment: My biggest problem is how can I trigger on the arrow being clicked. I saw this other post but it does not mention anything about the first part of my question.

Comment: Bind a `click` event handler to the element. That said, keep in mind that it takes some time to updates the select list and it could be that the browser closes the list again when it is updated. See also the tutorial: [FIND ME: USING SELECTORS AND EVENTS](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery#Find_me:_Using_selectors_and_events).

Comment: Why are people downvoting all the posters?

Comment: If you want a more detailed answer, post your JS code you have atm (with the Ajax call etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//When the #rowTopic_1 element is clicked
$("#rowTopic_1").click(function() {

  //Cache the element
  $this = $(this);

  //Load new content
  $.ajax({
    url: "yoururl",
    type: "POST",
    success: function(data) {
      //Remove the old content and replace with the returned data
      $this.empty().append(data);
    }
  });

});
```

For this to work you will need to use  a server side language to return html to the page in the format `<option value="00">Foo</option>`

Comment: For better performance I'd suggest to return a JSON-encoded list of your new options in name: value pairs. Saves some bandwidth and the new content can be rendered out earlier. Another question: why load the new content on a click? You could do that onDomReady for each selectbox... probably more userfriendly.

Comment: I agree Simon, i would load the select box's on page load, or even do it all server side personally. As for the JSON-encoded list, its also a great idea (y).

Answer (score 0):

```
 $.ajax({
      success:function(){
           $(this).html('insert html');
      }
 });
```

I believe without checking that should work :/

Comment: lol maybe it won't if the duplicate is has so much code to it

Comment: Jamie - I think you missed some bits.

Comment: It was mentioned in the question that AJAX is not a problem for @Anne

Comment: yup, this wasn't addressing the ajax, this was addressing the issue that on click you wanted to change the state of the clicked button. Obviously you will only want this to change on a successful ajax request.

Comment: in fact, the correct answer has followed my same route :) only gone into more detail yet i have been -1'd

Answer (score 0):

You need the `focus` event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#rowTopic_1').focus(function() {
        // ajax code here
   })
});
```

You can find it in the api [here](http://api.jquery.com/focus/).