# Show data from an array to a dynamic selectbox (jQuery - AJAX) in Laravel 4

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, arrays, laravel

I'm trying to implement a dynamic select box using jQuery and I have some problems...
I have a 'route' to access to my DB and get the data of the new select box:

```
Route::get('contenidos/comboasign/{asignatura_id}', array('uses' => 'ContenidoController@comboAsignBloque'));
```

My Controller:

```
public function comboAsignBloque($asignatura_id)
{
    if(Request::ajax()){
        $bloques = DB::table('bloques')->where('asignatura_id','=', $asignatura_id)->orderBy('nombre', 'asc')->lists('id','nombre');
        return json_encode(array("bloques" => $bloques));
    }
}
```

And, in my View I have the form and this js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     // Obtenemos los datos del selecbox1

     $("#select_asignatura").change(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

            var asignatura_id = $("#select_asignatura option:selected").val();

            // AJAX request
            $.get('comboasign/'+asignatura_id, function(data){
                // #select_bloque is the select where I want to show my new options
                var select = $('#select_bloque');

                select.empty();

                // select.html(data);

                var optionsarray = data.split(',');

                var seloption = " ";

                $.each(optionsarray, function(i){

                    seloption += '<option value="' + optionsarray[i] + '">' + optionsarray[i] + '</option>';
                    select.append(seloption);
                });

                  });
        });     
     });
```

I need something in my 'js' to show the data in my new 'selectbox_bloque', or maybe I'm not doing good in my Controller... If I set my data in a normal , I get something like this:

```
 {"bloques":{"bloque 1 mate":1,"Bloque 2 de Mate":6}}
```

I need to put this array into my select box and I can't find out how...
I really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You object duplication is because of this

```
var seloption = " ";

$.each(optionsarray, function(i){

    seloption += '<option value="' + optionsarray[i] + '">' + optionsarray[i] + '</option>';
    select.append(seloption);
```

Change it to

```
    var seloption = " ";

    $.each(optionsarray, function(i){

        seloption += '<option value="' + optionsarray[i] + '">' + optionsarray[i] + '</option>';
    )};
    select.append(seloption);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, use the browsers debugger to check that you have actually returned some data from the `$.get....` call.

As you are returning JSON data you can use

```
$.getJSON('comboasign/'+asignatura_id, function(data){
```

this will automatically convert the returned JSON string `(data)` to a javascript datatype, an array in your case as you converted a PHP array to JSON data using

```
json_encode(array("bloques" => $bloques));
```

Also you could make the returned data easier to access by doing just

```
json_encode( $bloques );
```

Comment: I have returned some data, as I wrote in my question, but the point is that I don't know how to show it properly.
I've tried your '$.getJSON()' but I don't get any response... :(

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20236611/how-to-remove-and-replace-select-options-using-jquery

Comment: Thank you, but my problem is that I don't know how to set the 'value'(id) and the 'text'(nombre) in every <option> from the array I obtain...

Comment: I got it...

My problem was in my Controller. I had to create an array (using a foreach) like this:

    $bloque_id = DB::table('bloques')->where('asignatura_id','=', $asignatura_id)->orderBy('nombre', 'asc')->lists('id','nombre');
   foreach ($bloque_id as $key => $value) {
    $resources[] = array("nombre" => $key, "id" => $value);
   }

   $resources_JSON_array = json_encode($resources);

   return $resources_JSON_array;

Comment: Then, in my 'js' I call to every value and text properly:

    $.each(myData, function(i){
          seloption += '<option value="' + myData[i].id + '">' + myData[i].nombre + '</option>';
          select.append(seloption);
         });

The only thing I need to fix now is that I'm obtaining some objects duplicated... :(