# show options in select tag when a specific option is selected in other select tag from json

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 3 select tags in my HTML document , and when i select 1st option from the 1st select tag, i want to show some other options in the second select tag which is hidden, but i need to load those options from external file like json. 
how can i do this ?

for e.x i have this object

```
var object = {
    usa: {
        californina: ['san fransisco',
                       'san diego'
        ],nevada: ['las vegas', 
                    'reno']
     }
}
```

when i select usa option in the 1st select tag, i want to show the states (california,nevada) in the second select box, and when i choose nevada option i want to show the city(las vegas, reno) in the 3d select tag!

i want all those options to be kept in external json file! 
how can i load the json file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to populate a cascading Dropdown with JQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18351921/how-to-populate-a-cascading-dropdown-with-jquery)

Comment: i need to load it from json file

Comment: Please emphasize that on the title.

Comment: You are right , sorry

Answer (score 0):

Having a json like this: {"resource":"A","literals":["B","C","D"]} and taking account you want read a external JSON file, you can follow the different answers for this post: [How to read an external local JSON file in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19706046/how-to-read-an-external-local-json-file-in-javascript).

After you read the information that you need, you can or append the options to your(s) select(s) ([What is the best way to add options to a select from an array with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170986/what-is-the-best-way-to-add-options-to-a-select-from-an-array-with-jquery)) or replace all the option and append again([How to remove and replace select options using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20236611/how-to-remove-and-replace-select-options-using-jquery))

Probably, you want add some events to do something after the user select an option. For that, use this post [jquery select change event get selected option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12750307/jquery-select-change-event-get-selected-option)

I hope this will help you,
Best Regards