# how to make the new option that has been added to a select tag as selected in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a Jquery script where I am doing an ajax call and the value that I get in return I am using it to add it in the select option , Drop down menu ,

My Problem is that its not showing as selected ,

The JS is as follows

```
(function($, window) {
      $.fn.replaceOptions = function(options) {
        var self, $option;

        this.empty();
        self = this;

        $.each(options, function(index, option){
          $option = $("<option></option>")
            .attr("value", option.value)
            .text(option.text);
          self.append($option);
        });
        this.prop('disabled', false);
      };
    })(jQuery, window);

$(document).on('click', ".add1", function () {
    var val1 = $(".selectLevel", $(this).parents("tr")).eq(0).val(),
        val2 = $(".selectLevel", $(this).parents("tr")).eq(1).val(),
        url = "http://www.xxxyz.com/xxx/xxx/web/ajax.php",
        val3 = $(this).closest('tr').find('input').val(),
        closeSelect = $(this).closest('td').find('select');

    if (val3 == '' || val3 == null) alert('You need to add value in the input box');
    else {
        var posting = $.post(url, {
            im_core: 'selectAjaxUpdate',
            geo_level1: val1,
            geo_level2: val2,
            geo_level3: val3,
            pais: <? php echo $_POST['pais'] ?>
        }).done(function (data) {
            var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
            $.each(obj, function (key, value) {
                myArray.push({
                    text: obj[key].value,
                    value: obj[key].id
                });
            });
            //$(closeSelect).html('myArray');
            $(closeSelect).replaceOptions(myArray);
        });
    }
});
```

Can any one help me , With this

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What is the `replaceOptions` function?

Comment: Please tell us if you are using any plugins for the dropdown menu

Comment: replaceOptions  could be a jquery extention function. refer this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801499/how-to-change-options-of-select-with-jquery

Comment: @Spokey no I am not using any plugin Replaceoption() is a Jquery extention function

Comment: @Spokey my bad wait I will update my question its function I have

Answer (score 0):

The problem in

```
$(closeSelect).replaceOptions(myArray);
```

try change to

```
closeSelect.replaceOptions(myArray);
```

And if you use replaceoptions method from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16654226/2021019),
it not support setting selected value,because it only take array of objects and appent them to select

Comment: Yes I am using it from the link , SO what do you suggest me to do inorder to fix this

Comment: I suggset rewrite replaceOptions method,It should take second parameter with selected value.

Comment: I came accross this small code snippet ,  

`$(closeSelect ,'option').filter(function() {
    return this.value.indexOf( val3 ) > -1;
    })
    .prop('selected', true);`   Tried to use it but it wont work

Comment: Can you give me a jsfiddle link ? I would be able to understand more properly.

Answer (score 0):

You are changing source of dropdown but you are not setting new value once you source gets change. You just need to set selected vaulue.

```
$(document).on('click', ".add1", function () {
    var val1 = $(".selectLevel", $(this).parents("tr")).eq(0).val(),
        val2 = $(".selectLevel", $(this).parents("tr")).eq(1).val(),
        url = "http://www.xxxyz.com/xxx/xxx/web/ajax.php",
        val3 = $(this).closest('tr').find('input').val(),
        closeSelect = $(this).closest('td').find('select');

    if (val3 == '' || val3 == null) alert('You need to add value in the input box');
    else {
        var posting = $.post(url, {
            im_core: 'selectAjaxUpdate',
            geo_level1: val1,
            geo_level2: val2,
            geo_level3: val3,
            pais: <? php echo $_POST['pais'] ?>
        }).done(function (data) {
            var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
            $.each(obj, function (key, value) {
                myArray.push({
                    text: obj[key].value,
                    value: obj[key].id
                });
            });
            //$(closeSelect).html('myArray');
            $(closeSelect).replaceOptions(myArray);

            //Set selectedValue over here
            $(closeSelect).val(yourSelectedValue);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Actually I am getting list of options from the Ajax and there I don't know which one has been selected , One thing That I can do is , when I am sending the value in ajax I can save it in a variable and use it later to match and prop it

Comment: yes. I did not find such variable in your code which was holding this value so I just put a placeholder yourSelectedValue there. You can replace it your vaule.

Comment: how about matching the new options with the string that I had passed in the Ajax to be added to the table, `$(closeSelect ,'option').filter(function() {
    return this.value.indexOf( val3 ) > -1;
    })
    .prop('selected', true);`  I tried this script but it wont work