# How to change thirdparty select tag value using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I have some third party gadget on my wordpress website and getting below code but it's giving me default currency for example JPY Japanese but I want to switch using Javascript and select USD from the list how I can implement some script which can select value="USD" when page load, I don't want manual USD selection all the time, when visitor want to change the currency they can change it from the list but I want to present default selection value as a USD. Javascript or php any method for wordpress or normal html code where I can select default value as USD.

```
<div class="currencyId">
<span class="label">
<span>Currency</span>
</span>
<span>
<select rel="currencyId" value="JPY" style="width: 124px;">
<option value="JPY">Japanese yen (JPY)</option></br>
<option value="AFN">Afghan afghani (AFN)</option></br>
<option value="ALL">Albanian lek (ALL)</option></br>
<option value="DZD">Algerian dinar (DZD)</option></br>
<option value="AOA">Angolan kwanza (AOA)</option></br>
<option value="ARS">Argentine peso (ARS)</option></br>
<option value="AMD">Armenian dram (AMD)</option></br>
<option value="AWG">Aruban florin (AWG)</option></br>
<option value="USD">United States dollar (USD)</option></br>
</select>
</span>
</div>
```

Waiting for some favorable reply. I want to implement code between

Comment: check here on how to replace existing options -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801499/how-to-change-options-of-select-with-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> using this you can change the value of select box when page loads

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('select').find('option[value=USD]').attr('selected','selected');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
   <option value="JPY">Japanese yen (JPY)</option>
<option value="AFN">Afghan afghani (AFN)</option>
<option value="ALL">Albanian lek (ALL)</option>
<option value="DZD">Algerian dinar (DZD)</option>
<option value="AOA">Angolan kwanza (AOA)</option>
<option value="ARS">Argentine peso (ARS)</option>
<option value="AMD">Armenian dram (AMD)</option>
<option value="AWG">Aruban florin (AWG)</option>
<option value="USD">United States dollar (USD)</option>
</select>
```

Comment: It might be better to use the following query:

    $('#currencyId select').find('option[value=USD]').attr('selected','selected');

otherwise the code will target all select tags on the page.

Comment: yep ofcourse, it is a very common thing for developers, i think he is aware of this