# Symfony5 Form multiple select (choices list) data auto-update with AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony5

I have a location form with three "select" (choices list) : country, area and department. These "select" have by default all the list of country, area and department. I want to let my user choose a country first or an area or a department.

**What I want to do:**
When an user choose a country, datas in area change depending of it. Same between area and department.

**What I have:**

- When I choose **a country first then an area**, datas auto-update works between country and area **but with area to department, the AJAX request is not launched**.
- But if I choose **directly an area** then **the AJAX request is launched but it does not update the data in department**.
- However, in the form, when I comment the part concerning country and area auto-update, **the AJAX request is launched and the auto-update between area and department works.**

Here my form :

```php
//src/Form/LocationType.php
class LocationType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('country', EntityType::class, [
        'class' => Country::class,
            ])
            ->add('area', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Area::class,
                'required' => false
            ])
            ->add('department', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Department::class,
                'required' => false
            ]);
            
        //The part I comment for makes the auto-update between area and department works
        $formArea = function(FormInterFace $form, Country $country = null) {
            if($country === null) {
                $form->add('area', EntityType::class, [
                    'class' => Area::class,
                    'required' => false
                ]);
            }
            else {
                $areas = $country->getAreas();
                $form->add('area', EntityType::class, [
                    'class' => Area::class,
                    'choices' => $areas,
                    'required' => false
                ]);
            }
        };

        $builder->get('country')->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
            function (FormEvent $event) use ($formArea){
                $country = $event->getForm()->getData();
                $formArea($event->getForm()->getParent(), $country);
            }
        );
        //

        $formDepartment = function(FormInterFace $form, Area $area = null) {
            if($area === null) {
                $form->add('department', EntityType::class, [
                    'class' => Department::class,
                    'required' => false
                ]);
            }
            else {
                $departments = $area->getDepartments();
                $form->add('department', EntityType::class, [
                    'class' => Department::class,
                    'choices' => $departments,
                    'required' => false
                ]);
            }
        };

        $builder->get('area')->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
            function (FormEvent $event) use ($formDepartment){
                $area = $event->getForm()->getData();
                $formDepartment($event->getForm()->getParent(), $area);
            }
        );
}
```

And JS code with AJAX call:

```js
//assets/js/selectCountryAreaDepartment.js
window.onload = () => {
    let country = document.querySelector("#location_country");

    country.addEventListener("change", function() {
        let form = this.closest("form");
        let data = this.name + "=" + this.value;
        console.log(data);
        fetch(form.action, {
            method: form.getAttribute("method"),
            body: data,
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset:UTF-8"
            }
        })
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(html => {
            let content = document.createElement("html");
            content.innerHTML = html;
            let area = content.querySelector("#location_area");
            document.querySelector("#location_area").replaceWith(area);
            console.log(area);

        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        })
    });

    let area = document.querySelector("#location_area");

    area.addEventListener("change", function() {
        let formArea = this.closest("form");
        let dataArea = this.name + "=" + this.value;
        //console.log(formArea);
        console.log(dataArea);
        fetch(formArea.action, {
            method: formArea.getAttribute("method"),
            body: dataArea,
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset:UTF-8"
            }
        })
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(html => {
            let contentArea = document.createElement("html");
            contentArea.innerHTML = html;
            let department = contentArea.querySelector("#location_department");
            document.querySelector("#location_department").replaceWith(department);
            console.log(department);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        })
    });

}
```

This code is based on this French tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f7tdb30evUk

Comment: I do not know symfony at all but I wonder why there is not closing `]);` in the `else` section ot the function declaration : `$formDepartment = function(FormInterFace $form, Area $area = null)`.  To be more precise, `'required' => false` -> `'required' => false ]);`

Comment: @Stef1611 Sorry, It was just a copy/paste mistake.

Comment: My `else` in `$formDepartment` is correctly closed in my code. I accidently erased it in my StackOverflow question. It's corrected now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By removing *add()* in null case in *formModifiers* *formArea* and *formDepartment* it avoid to "reset" select when an other select is used :

```php
//src/Form/LocationType.php
// …
        // formModifier
        $formArea = function(FormInterFace $form, LocationCountry $country = null) {
            if($country != null)
            {
                $areas = $country->getAreas();
            $form->add('area', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => LocationArea::class,
                'choices' => $areas,
                'placeholder' => 'select now an area',
                'required' => false
            ]);
            }
        };

        $builder->get('country')->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
            function (FormEvent $event) use ($formArea){
                $country = $event->getForm()->getData();
                $formArea($event->getForm()->getParent(), $country);
            }
        );

        // formModifier
        $formDepartment = function(FormInterFace $form, LocationArea $area = null) {
            if($area != null) 
            {
                $departments = $area->getDepartments();
            $form->add('department', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => LocationDepartment::class,
                'choices' => $departments,
                'placeholder' => 'select now a department',
                'required' => false,
                'choice_label' => function ($departments) {
                    return '['.$departments->getCode().']-'.$departments->getName();
                }
            ]);
            }
        };
```

The `area.addEventListener` is removed by update area select, so it is necessary to re-activate the eventListener after update area select, so I create a function `area_addEnventListener()`

```js
window.onload = () => {
    let country = document.querySelector("#location_country");

    country.addEventListener("change", function() {
        let form = this.closest("form");
        let data = this.name + "=" + this.value;
        fetch(form.action, {
            method: form.getAttribute("method"),
            body: data,
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset:UTF-8"
            }
        })
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(html => {
            let content = document.createElement("html");
            content.innerHTML = html;
            let area = content.querySelector("#location_area");
            document.querySelector("#location_area").replaceWith(area);
            area_addEnventListener(area);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        })
    });

    let area = document.querySelector("#location_area");

    area_addEnventListener(area);
}

function area_addEnventListener(area_select) {
    area_select.addEventListener("change", function() {
        let formArea = area_select.closest("form");
        let dataArea = area_select.name + "=" + area_select.value;
        fetch(formArea.action, {
            method: formArea.getAttribute("method"),
            body: dataArea,
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset:UTF-8"
            }
        })
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(html => {
            let contentArea = document.createElement("html");
            contentArea.innerHTML = html;
            let department = contentArea.querySelector("#location_department");
            document.querySelector("#location_department").replaceWith(department);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        })
    });
}
```