# How to populate the json when select the option in one drop down using j query?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When i am selecting the city in first select box show the city relented data

how to populate the the json when selecting city in first drop down and how to show the relented data when select the different city?

this is html

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var cityData = [{
      cityName: 'Bengaluru',
      value: "Bengaluru",
      data: [{
          movieName: 'ABC',
          theaterName: 'Tulsi Theatre'
        },
        {
          movieName: 'DEF',
          theaterName: 'PVR'
        },
        {
          movieName: 'GHI',
          theaterName: 'Srinivasa Theatre'
        }
      ]
    },


    {
      cityName: 'Hyderabad',
      value: "Hyderabad",
      data: [{
          movieName: '123',
          theaterName: 'Theatre1'
        },
        {
          movieName: '456',
          theaterName: 'PVR2'
        },
        {
          movieName: '789',
          theaterName: 'Theatre3'
        }
      ]
    },

    {
      cityName: 'Guntur',
      value: "Guntur",
      data: [{
          movieName: 'ABC1',
          theaterName: 'Theatre4'
        },
        {
          movieName: 'DEF2',
          theaterName: 'PVR3'
        },
        {
          movieName: 'GHI3',
          theaterName: 'Theatre5'
        }
      ]
    },

    {
      cityName: 'Ongole',
      value: "Ongole",
      data: 'currently not available'
    }
  ];
  $("#selectCity").on('change', function() {
    var locations = cityData[$(this).val()];
    var locationString = 'locations';
    console.log(locations)
    $.each(locations, function(i, item) {

      console.log(JSON.stringify(item));

      // OUCH!!! 

      locationString += '<option value="' + item.id + '">' + item.name + '</option>';
    });
    //console.log(locationString)
    $('#secondselectbox').html(locationString);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="UserData">
  <h1>MyMovie-Ticket-Booking</h1>
  <select class="selectCity" id="selectCity">
        <option value="City">Select City</option>
        <option value="Bengaluru">Bengaluru</option>
        <option value="Hyderabad">Hyderabad</option>
        <option value="Guntur">Guntur</option>
        <option value="Ongole">Ongole</option>
       </select>
  <span id="welcome"> </span>
</div>
<div>
  <select id="secondselectbox"></select>
  <select id="secondselectbox"></select>
</div>
```

when i am  selecting the city Bangalore show the Bangalore theater list and movie list but it is showing the undefined ....

Comment: Why are there 2 `select` box with the same id?

Comment: i want to  display theater and movie name at a time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were not retrieving your 'locations' data correctly, per your json structure.

Also, the options do not have an 'id', 'item' in the json.

Do change the last select's id to something unique (say 'thirdselectbox'...).

Modify your select's change listener to:

```
$("#selectCity").on('change', function() {
    var locations = cityData.filter(c => c.cityName === $(this).val())[0].data;
    var locationString = '';
    var locationString2 = '';
    console.log(locations)
    $.each(locations, function(i, item) {

        console.log(JSON.stringify(item));
        locationString += '<option value="' + item.theaterName + '">' + item.theaterName + '</option>';
        locationString2 += '<option value="' + item.movieName + '">' + item.movieName + '</option>';
    });
    $('#secondselectbox').html(locationString);
    $('#thirdselectbox').html(locationString2);
});
```

See  [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6d5dxe6y/).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Comment: let me give it a try then

Comment: when i am selecting the city in first option it will display the reelected city information movies and theater list of city

Comment: Also included a fiddle for your reference.

Comment: but it is not showing the theater list only display the movie list

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160366/discussion-between-venu-chowdary-and-dev8080).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you update your select element with necessary data. Just placing the JSON and including it won't solve the issue. You can see a tutorial here on [how to update a select element dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801499/how-to-change-options-of-select-with-jquery).

And don't use two elements with one ID. It can cause more problems. You can use different ID's for the two select elements.

Comment: yes you said is correct don't use two elements with one ID

Comment: It creates a lot of confusions specially in dynamic applications.

Answer (score 0):

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
  var cityData = [{
      cityName: 'Bengaluru',
      value: "Bengaluru",
      data: [{
          movieName: 'ABC',
          theaterName: 'Tulsi Theatre'
        },
        {
          movieName: 'DEF',
          theaterName: 'PVR'
        },
        {
          movieName: 'GHI',
          theaterName: 'Srinivasa Theatre'
        }
      ]
    },


    {
      cityName: 'Hyderabad',
      value: "Hyderabad",
      data: [{
          movieName: '123',
          theaterName: 'Theatre1'
        },
        {
          movieName: '456',
          theaterName: 'PVR2'
        },
        {
          movieName: '789',
          theaterName: 'Theatre3'
        }
      ]
    },

    {
      cityName: 'Guntur',
      value: "Guntur",
      data: [{
          movieName: 'ABC1',
          theaterName: 'Theatre4'
        },
        {
          movieName: 'DEF2',
          theaterName: 'PVR3'
        },
        {
          movieName: 'GHI3',
          theaterName: 'Theatre5'
        }
      ]
    },

    {
      cityName: 'Ongole',
      value: "Ongole",
      data: 'currently not available'
    }
  ];
  $("#selectCity").on('change', function() 
  {
$('#secondselectbox').html("");
var selectedlocations = $("#selectCity").val();
    var locationString = 'locations';
    var locationlist=cityData
    $.each(locationlist, function(i, item) {

    var EachLocationdetail=JSON.stringify(item);
        var _json=JSON.parse(EachLocationdetail);
    if(_json.cityName==selectedlocations)
     {

      $.each(_json.data, function() 
      {

        locationString += '<option value="' +this.movieName + '">' + this.movieName  + '</option>'; 
    });

         }

    });
    //console.log(locationString)
    $('#secondselectbox').html(locationString);
  });

});
```

**.**

[Try this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ConnectRohitAt/mqy6d673/)