# How to change the value of an element based on the users input

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I have 1 option in my dropdown w/c is "Others".

If I select the "Others", a textarea will show up and I can input whatever I want.

Is there a way that I can replace the value of the `<option value="Others">Others</option>`, based on the input text in the textarea.

Comment: Do you use jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use jQuery, you can check this answer to modify the options of the select drop down list.

[How to change options of  with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1801515/5693784)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check value of text area and using if statements with text area value as condition you can change value of  . Use onblur event.